# "node contents" is no more available in label, what's going on?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Normally a label is a node and we can use it as such, at least I think I was able to do it before version 3.1 of TikZ.

Now when I try to use `node contents` in `label`, for example like this :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\node[label={[node contents=B]}]{A};
\end{document}
```

I receive the following error

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

This is the same error that we obtain if we use `node contents` style within non empty node, like this `\node[node contents=B]{A};`.

**So my question is :** Has something changed in the way labels are treated in TikZ since version 3.1 ?

Comment: for the second error: `\tikz\node[node contents=B];` works (as expected). use `node contents={...}` meas that to you not declare its contains again.

Comment: @Zarko I know how to use `node contents`:) The example of `\node[node contents=B]{A};` is here just to say that may be for some reason the label node `label={[node contents=B]}` is not considered as "empty" in 3.1.

Comment: well, i newer use such a way of labeling of nodes. to my opinion it is against to basic concept of the use of labels. so if this works in older version, probably was not  by intention.

Comment: label is not a standard node, but node which you add a node. actually on the syntax of label you can look as follows: `label=<position>:<node content>`. so you can not nest `node contents=...` in `node contest=...`. i doubt that this has been possible in any version of `tikz`.

Comment: @Zarko it was not the case before, version 3.1 broke [some code](https://github.com/kpym/tikz-nicepoints/blob/86f7999/tikzlibrarynicepoints.code.tex#L60) that used to work fine. And the label syntax is `/tikz/label=[options]angle:text` (with options) where all parts are optional (you can check for example `label={[draw]}`). And before the label was like any other node.

Comment: I guess you wouldn't accept "yes" as the answer to  "Has something changed in the way labels are treated in TikZ since version 3.1 ?", would you? ;-)

Comment: @marmot this reminds me of [that](https://i.imgur.com/oVMDut5.jpg) :)

Comment: If you think that 3.1 broke something: make a bug report at the pgf bug tracker. That's the right place. Don't expect the maintainers to hunt down such issue reports here. https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have already reported bugs (like [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/484/)) and I have contributed to the project (like in [this case](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/merge-requests/3/)), so I know how it works ;) If I ask the question here is because I want to be sure that this is a bug, before to report it. And I want to know if somebody on TeX.SX have an idea what's going on. May be this is an intentional change in 3.1 that have a lot of benefices, but also this small inconvenience.

Comment: The only one who (without lots of digging) can know if the change is intentional and even if it is a bug are the maintainer. Who else do you expect to go to the code changes to find out when and why the change happened? So ask them. It is nonsense not to fill in a bug report only for fear that you are perhaps wrong. It won't hurt you if they close the issue if it is not a bug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer here we disagree about `It won't hurt you if they close the issue` : the maintainers are not so many and have a lot of work to do.  So spending a time to close issues hurts (not me). I think that is our duty to verify, as much as possible, before to make a bug request, by respect to the maintainers, their work and the time they spend to help us.

Comment: Most maintainer (and this includes me) like bug reports. Even more if they contain a short simple minimal example that clearly shows that something changed. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/how-to-encourage-people-to-send-bug-reports-instead-of-using-sx-as-kind-of-bugtr

Comment: Even an empty content *and* a `node contents` is an error: `\node[node contents=B]{};`. So, IMHO, a label with an empty text *and* a `node contents` is also an error...

Comment: To answer your question: yes, something has changed... But perhaps it is not a bug.

Comment: @PaulGaborit This is exactly what I'm saying, but that was not the case before 3.1. So for some reason the labels now have `{}` probably. So my question is "what is the reason for this?", because if there is no obvious reason, or if the same goal can be achieved by making it compatible with `node contents`, well this will be a bug, IMO.

Comment: @Kpym As Ulrike says: _The only people who can tell if the change is intentional or if it's a bug is the developers._

Comment: @PaulGaborit I have seen (many times) on this website texperts that are not part of the tikz team answer low level questions, but may be this people not here any more or they are not interested in this question. In any case if I have no answer here I'll raise an issue on SF (as I always do).

Comment: @Kpym I gave my opinion: the current behavior of TikZ is not a bug since it makes sense. What more do you expect as an answer?

Comment: @PaulGaborit well "make sens" is subjective point of view, IMO. You can consider that in `/tikz/label=[options]angle:text` the `text` part is set using `{text}` after the label node, or using `node contents=text`. Why the fist option should be considered as "natural" if the only benefits is to make labels incompatible with standard node keys ? I expect somebody to tell me something like "In 3.1 the labels were being redesigned because ... and the price to pay for this is ...". Who knows, I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that [was fixed](https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/c6979) and will be available in [v3.1.3](https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/releases) probably.